# How do I stop rendering off screen sprites in starling?

Tags: arrays, optimization, flash-builder, sprite, starling-framework

I'm having trouble deleting my enemies as they go off screen in starling. I get performance issues after a while because my enemies array just keeps growing and growing.

This is the code I have that makes enemies as well as the update function at the end of my class.

```
private function makeEnemies():void
    {
        enemySpawnCounter++;

        if (enemySpawnCounter > enemySpawnDelay)
        {
            enemySpawnCounter = 0;
            enemySpawnDelay -= difficultyRate;
            difficulty += difficultyRate;
            makeEnemy();
        }
    }

    private function makeEnemy():void
    {
        var i:int;
        for (i = 0; i < Math.floor(difficulty); i++)
        {
            var newEnemy:Enemy = new SnowBall();

            newEnemy.x = 925;
            newEnemy.y = Math.random() * 375 + 50;
            //trace(newEnemy.x); trace(newEnemy.y);
            newEnemy.xVel = (-Math.random() * difficulty) - 5;
            newEnemy.sinMeter = Math.random() * 10;
            newEnemy.bobValue = Math.random() * difficulty;

            enemiesLayer.addChild(newEnemy);
            enemies.push(newEnemy);

            if (newEnemy.x <= 0)
            {
                enemies.splice(i, 1);
                enemiesLayer.removeChild(newEnemy);
            }
        }
    }
private function update():void
    {
        trace(enemies.length, lasers.length);

        for each (var enemy:Enemy in enemies)
        {
            enemy.update();
        }

        for each (var laser:Laser in lasers)
        {
            laser.update();
            newHitTest(laser);
        }

        makeEnemies();
    }
```

And here is my enemy class...

```
package objects
{
import starling.events.Event;
import starling.display.Sprite;
import objects.Laser;

public class Enemy extends Sprite
{
    public static const PURGE_EVENT:String = "ENEMY_PURGE";

    public var sinMeter:Number;
    public var bobValue:Number;
    public var status:String;

    public var xVel:Number;
    public var yVel:Number;

    public function Enemy()
    {
        status = "OK";
        bobValue = 0.1;
        sinMeter = 0;
        xVel = 0;
        yVel = 0;
    }

    public function destroy():void
    {
        status = "Dead";
        visible = false;
    }

    public function update():void
    {
        x += xVel;
        y += yVel;

        if (x < 0)
        {
            trace("Dispatching Enemy Escaped!");
            dispatchEvent(new Event(Laser.PURGE_EVENT, true, false));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Anybody know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Detect if they are touching the screen, I have never used starling but I think there might be some sort of collision detection, so make a rect or surface that is the size of the screen that stays with the screen, then only draw the enemies that are colliding with that surface.